# Use GWT for Ajax Website

Tags: java, php, ajax, gwt

Hello I am programming a website and like how GWT works. My host only supports PHP and no Java and thefore also no GWT. I was wondering if i could user GWT to program a fully Ajax website with php requests to the database so that it can run on my webserver. 
Thanks

jan behang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The bridge between GWT and PHP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-gwtphp/)

> Google Web Toolkit (GWT) applications, apart from connecting to
>   servlets in time-honored Java™ fashion, can also use PHP Web services
>   to send and receive data in XML. You'll explore methods to generate
>   XML documents and process them, both in the Java language and in PHP.

And also check out [Basic tips for using GWT with PHP](http://www.drivenbycuriosity.com/mywp/?p=30) as well. 
And also almost forget referencing GWT's own documentation, it will also teach you how to send JSON which is being widely used data format among AJAX developers. Here is the step-by-step explanation how to build the StockWatcher application using GWT with PHP: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/GettingStartedJSON

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was wondering how i would setup my Eclipse GWT project for user of a PHP webserver.

Comment: form this http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/usingeclipse.html you can find how to setup GWT for eclipse

Comment: The project setup is going to be the same, but debugging and using Dev Mode will be a little different - you wont need the built-in server that GWT provides, you'll need to start your own server. More details on how to tell GWT that another server: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s